# Google cloud - connect: connection refused with cloud build triggers

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to auto deploy an app from GitHub to Google cloud.  For reference I checked similar example with firebase from -  https://fireship.io/lessons/ci-cd-with-google-cloud-build/

but I am getting following error while trying to run trigger -

```
Pulling image: grc.io/cloud-builders/npm
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
Using default tag: latest
Error response from daemon: Get https://grc.io/v2/: dial tcp 64.98.145.30:443: connect: connection refused
```

**Updated** as per **Cloud Ace** comment  My **cloudbuild.yaml** file have following codes -

```
steps:
  #install
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['install']

   #build
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
    args: ['run', 'build']

   #deploy
  - name: 'gcr.io/mytest-240512/npm'
    args: ['deploy']
```

Please help me to fix this error. Thank you!!

Now getting another error -

```
Step #1: ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Permissions error fetching application [apps
/mytest-240512]. Please make sure you are using the correct project ID and that
you have permission to view applications on the project.
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a typo in your `cloudbuild.yaml`, change `grc.io` to `gcr.io`

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, sorry for the silly typo, I fixed it but now getting another error - npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2019-05-14T03_59_11_566Z-debug.log

Comment: What's your package.json look like? did you define scripts in it?

Comment: Package.json looks like - https://docs.google.com/document/d/14X5X8jsAJ2eQkQkMcvuoJ_EnUgSy27Mkr2zhgymwL5c/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There's no `build` in your package.json, scripts section

Comment: Can you please let me know how should it looks like or some reference which I can follow and auto deploy app from GitHub to Google cloud?

Comment: It depends on your local process. How do you build your app locally?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193298/discussion-between-sachin-vairagi-and-cloud-ace).